# Recursive Callbacks to create a familly tree

Tags: javascript, recursion, keystonejs

I am trying to create a family tree with callback functions nested in callback functions, i'm hoping to get at least 5 generation. the function receive the person's id, which then look for everyone in the database that has the property 'father' with the same id.

---

This is the function for getting the children of the person

```
var getChildren=function (person, callback) {
        keystone.list('Person').model.find().where('father', person.id).exec(function(err, children) {
            callback(children);
        })
    }
```

this is how i use the callback function

```
function getFamilyTree(person){
        getChildren(person, function(children){
            person.children=children;
            for (var i=0;i<person.children.length;i++) {
                !function outer(i){
                    if (isNotEmpty(person.children[i])){
                        getChildren(person.children[i],function(children){
                                person.children[i].children=children;
                                for (var j=0;j<person.children[i].children.length;j++){
                                    !function outer(j){
                                        if (isNotEmpty(person.children[i].children[j])){
                                            getChildren(person.children[i].children[j],function(children){
                                                    person.children[i].children[j].children=children;
                                                    for (var k=0;k<person.children[i].children[j].children.length;k++){
                                                        !function outer(k){
                                                            if (isNotEmpty(person.children[i].children[j].children[k])){
                                                                getChildren(person.children[i].children[j].children[k],function(children){
                                                                    person.children[i].children[j].children[k].children=children;

                                                                })
                                                            }
                                                        }(k);
                                                    }
                                            })
                                        }

                                    }(j);
                                }
                        });
                    }

                }(i);
            }
        })
    }
```

as you can see, it is very complicated. It works, but sometimes it doesn't retrieve all 5 generation but only 4 or 3, sometimes even 1 and i don't know why, please help my guys, and i'm also a new comer so please be easy with me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) instead of callbacks, you could use a recursive [`async` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to resolve trees of arbitrary depth:

```js
function getChildren(person) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    keystone.list('Person').model.find().where('father', person.id).exec((err, children) => {
      if(err) reject(err);
      else resolve(children);
    });
  });
}

async function getFamilyTree(person, maxDepth, depth=0) {
  if(depth >= maxDepth) return person;
  const children = (await getChildren(person)).filter(isNotEmpty);
  person.children = await Promise.all(
    children.map(child => getFamilyTree(child, maxDepth, depth + 1))
  );
  return person;
}

getFamilyTree({id: 'rootPersonId'}, 5)
  .then(tree => console.log(tree))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: thanks alot for the comment, because of how the front-end works, i need to retrieve the full JSON family tree of the person. Also, i tried your code out but it only retrieved 1 generation of the person, i don't think i know why though

Comment: I'd throw some `console.log` calls in there. I don't think this logic is wrong, but it's hard to know without seeing the results of the `getChildren` calls or the data you're querying.

Comment: so by using getChildren, it would retrieve the person's children in the form of an array of objects, each object will contain information about each child. When a person doesn't have any children, it would simply return a blank array.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to use recursion. I don't know exactly how your data looks, or how `getChildren` works, but this should point you in the right direction:

```
function getFamilyTree ( person ) {
    getChildren( person, function( children ) {
        person.children = children;
        for ( var i = 0; i < person.children.length ) {
             getFamilyTree( person.children[ i ] );
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you can do to simplify the code is to pull out the `outer` function that you use multiple times throughout the `getFamilyTree` function so you don't repeat it all over the place. It'll need an update to take the child node as a parameter instead of the index for simplicity.

Since your callback is the same every time, you can pull it out into it's own function. It'll need a slight update to take in the parent item, since you are constantly referencing the `person` variable throughout the callback.

Your `outer` function can be something like:

```
function outer(child) {
    if (isNotEmpty(child)) {
        getChildren(child, getChildrenCallback);
    }
}
```

And then the `getChildrenCallback` will be:

```
function getChildrenCallback(children, parent) {
    parent.children = children;
    for ( var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        outer(child[i]);
    }
```

}